# Make a package work as just one import

Tags: python

I have a package in my project containing many *.py source files (each consisting of one class in most cases, and named by the class). I would like it so that when this package is imported, all of the files in the package are also imported, so that I do not have to write

```
import Package.SomeClass.SomeClass
import Package.SomeOtherClass.SomeOtherClass
import ...
```

just to import every class in the package. Instead I can just write

```
import Package
```

and every class is available in Package, so that later code in the file can be:

```
my_object = Package.SomeClass()
```

What's the easiest way of doing this in __init__.py? If different, what is the most general way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual method is inside `package/__init__.py`

```
from .SomeClass import SomeClass
```

Comment: But I still need to do this for every class, only just in \__init__.

Comment: @Dylan, yes and if you look at most python libraries, that's what they do.

Comment: OK then, I'll take your word for it. It just seems inelegant, un-Pythonic.

Comment: @Dylan, this is partially helped by not always putting every class in its own file. Python programmers are more likely to have multiple classes per file.

Answer (score 1):

As Winston put it, the thing to do is to have an `__init__.py` file where all your classes are available in the module (global)  namespace.

One way to do is, is to have a

```
from .myclasfile import MyClass
```

line for each class in your package, and that is not bad.

But, of course, this being Python, you can "automagic" this by doing something like this in `__init__.py`

```
import glob
for module_name in glob.glob("*.py"):
    class_name = module_name.split(".")[0]
    mod = __import__(module_name)
    globals()[class_name] = getattr(mod, class_name)

del glob
```